# How to create a GIF image that play once and freeze on last frame

Tags: gif

How to create a GIF image that play once and freeze on last frame.
I already made the loop property to 1, so first problem is solved.
But after animation finishes, gif is not freezing at last frame, it is to going back to first frame.

Comment: Solved!!! I added last frame of gif image as a background image. When gif animation gets completed, it is hidden and background image is visible. It gives the appearance that gif animation is stopping at last frame.

Comment: No other solution for this??

Answer (score 6):

You need to change the gif's loop count to 1.

Here's an online tool that lets you do that for free. https://ezgif.com/loop-count

Answer (score 0):

If your GIF happens to be a video GIF (`.gifv`), you first need to convert it into a "normal" GIF before you will succeed with setting the loop count to 1. Conversion can also be done online for free (e.g., at https://ezgif.com/video-to-gif).