# White screen problem when change background image

Tags: jquery, css

I have gif playing on background image, gif ends in ~5 seconds and after 5 seconds I change the gif to the png file.
While changing gif to png on background, there is white screen for a moment. I try to preload png image but didnt work.

How can I solve it?

Thank you.

edit:
my code is below, the png file I replaced is last frame of that gif.

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        setInterval(function () {
            $('#alumni_body').css("background-image", "url( {{ url("static/alumni/assets/media/background/pwc-alumni-login-video.png") }} )");
        }, 4000);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: First of all, please go read [ask] and [mre], and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to create a GIF image that play once and freeze on last frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23927908/how-to-create-a-gif-image-that-play-once-and-freeze-on-last-frame)

Comment: Please provide your existing code with your question.

Comment: @Ken hey added my existing code, thanks

Comment: Where is the code where you preload the image?

Answer (score 0):

because that moment the background is white it's loading the png file, you need to say, change background after the png was loaded:

```
setInterval(function () {
    $('<img/>').attr('src', 'static/alumni/assets/media/background/pwc-alumni-login-video.png').on('load', function(){
        $(this).remove();
        $('#alumni_body').css("background-image", "url( {{ url("static/alumni/assets/media/background/pwc-alumni-login-video.png") }} )");
    });
}, 4000);
```